# How can I design a secure content verification web application?

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, spring, postgres

In my country, there is a high number of fraudulent doctor's sick letter as they are manually written on paper. I'm designing a web application to combat this issue and have the whole process electronic.

My current thinking is that when the doctor issues the sick letter on the application, the app generates a unique identifier like a UUID but a human-friendly readable unique identifier which is stored in the database table alongside the sick letter's metadata(leave_start_date,leave_end_date etc) then email the generated letter to the patient which he/she will submit to his employer.

The employer will verify the legitimacy of the sick letter by providing the leave_start_date,leave_end_date and the unique identifier and query the database, if the query finds a record, the application will confirm that it's a valid sick letter.

My questions are as follows:

- Are there any issues you can think with this design?
- Performance concerns?
- Security concerns?
- Data privacy concerns?

I will be using Spring Boot(REST API), Postgresql and Keycloak as my stack. Will have a Javascript front end and mobile client.

[image: My current database design]

Comment: I'm confused as to why there appears to be a link between gender and address. EDIT: never mind, the line goes from Practioner, behind Address, and to Gender. I guess it's a problem with the tool.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Yes, it was a tool think, I have updated the image to make it clearer.

Comment: Someone could copy a legitimate letter, change the name, and if it only verifies the start and end date, the employer will see that the record exists and they won't know it's for a different person. So everyone could get the same days off.